# count messages two users in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am creating message conversation script between two users in PHP MYSQLI.I want to know how to count unread message between two users.My script not showing anything.

my database pm table

```
id  from_id     to_id    msg               sent_date              read     
1   2           3        hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20    1                
2   3           2        fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58    0               
3   2           3        hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34    1                  
4   5           2        hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40    0
```

Here is my source code

```
<?php
$unread_messages = 0;       
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}

$sql =  ("SELECT  COUNT(*) AS unread_messages
FROM    pm
WHERE   pm.to_id = ? and pm.from_id=from_id
        AND read = 0");
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
 $stmt->bind_param('i', $session_id);
 $stmt->execute();
}

$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $unread_messages;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating message conversation script between two users.

I would phrase this as:

```
select sum(*) cnt_unread
from pm
where 
    read = 0
    and (
        (pm.from_id = :userid1 and pm.to_id = :userid2)
        or (pm.from_id = :userid2 and pm.to_id = :userid1)
    )
```

This gives you the count of unread messages between `:userid1` and `:userid2` (whether from user 1 to user 2 or the other way around).

Comment: display like this message Fatal error: Call to a member function get_result() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\npm\cons.php on line 392

Comment: i dont know how to add it can you add to my code plz bro

Comment: @previn: please check for errors after `prepare()` and `execute()`, and then share the relevant SQL error message.

Comment: i added like this but display zero only $sql =  ("select sum(seen = 0) cnt_unread
from pm
where 
    (pm.from_id = from_id and pm.to_id = to_id)
    or (pm.from_id = from_id and pm.to_id = ?)");

Comment: @previn: please run the query exactly as provided. My query expects two parameters `:userid1` and `:userid2`, yours has just one.

Comment: display like this message Fatal error: Call to a member function get_result() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\npm\cons.php on line 395

Comment: @previn: check for errors... see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) for how to proceed.

Comment: Anyone can help me plz

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @u1 = 2;  -- id of first user
SET @u2 = 3;  -- id of 2nd user

SELECT count(`read`) as unread FROM pm 
WHERE `read` = 0 AND (from_id in (@u1,@u2) OR to_id in (@u1,@u2));
```

Comment: i checked display zero value only

Comment: first problem is using "read" as field name while it is a keyword in mysql. this problem can be solved by surrounding it with symbol ` as `read`

Comment: another advice is to work directly with database until you get expected results then move you SQL to PHP code.